# Switching styles (Class) on a function that show and hide a div tag content

Tags: jquery, css

I see a lot of resource on show/hide content using JQuery but what I don't know is how I can switch the style on this function as well. I can switch the text that display but I am using a button as a background image in a anchor tag.

Here is what I need to do. The button is default to Show More but When the button is click the content is visible; I would like to switch the class/style so that the button indicate Show Less.

Finally, how do I add this to more than one area in the page, do I need to create separate functions for each area?

Here is the JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#additionalContentBox').hide(); 
  $('.readmore').toggle(function(){ 
    $('#additionalContentBox').show(); 
  }, 
  function(){ 
    $('#additionalContentBox').hide();
    $('.readless').toggle(function(){ 
  }); 
});
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<a href="#/" class="readmore readless">Read Full Article</a>

<div id="additionalContentBox">
<p>pulvinar tellus. Maurtis commodo urna at dui bibendum quis euismod velit egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et. ante ipsum primis in faucibus</p>
</div>
```

Finally, the CSS:

```
.readmore{
    display: block;
    background-image: url(img/readmore15.png);
    text-indent: -10000px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom left;
    display: block;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: -14px;
}


.readless{
    background-image: url(img/readmore15.png);
    background-position: top left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something simple, like :

```
$('#your-link').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('readless');
    $('#your-div').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your 'a' tag an ID and select it using that in your jQuery.

Give the ID the generic CSS properties for the button.

Also keep the class of 'readmore' on it too start with and in the CSS just give it the background properties for 'readmore'.

When it is clicked the first time use jQuery to remove the 'readmore' class and add the 'readless' class.

```
jQuery("#myID").removeClass("readmore").addClass("readless")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your markup slightly to make "additionalContentBox" a class rather than an ID because you are probably going to have more than one. Preferably I would also give that element a default style 'display:none' so it doesn't have to wait for the JS to hide. Alos, I might start with the element NOT having the "readless" class yet. So the markup would look like this:

```
 <a href="#/" class="readmore">Read Full Article</a>
<div class="additionalContentBox" style="display: none;">
<p>pulvinar tellus. Maurtis commodo urna at dui bibendum quis euismod velit egestas.    Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et. ante ipsum primis in faucibus</p>
</div>
```

Then I'd set up the jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.readmore').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('readless')){
      $(this).removeClass('readless');
    }else{
      $(this).addClass('readless');
    };
   $(this).next('.additionalContentBox').toggle('fast');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks John and everyone, so what's the better way to apply this to more than one area on the page or do I simply make news styles and copy everything?